# Why isn't my `meta_query` array functioning properly?

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, meta-value

I am trying to include a meta_query to only show the `'post_type' => 'want-to-sell-post'` that have the key  `'key' => '_wpcf_belongs_artist_id',`.

Right now, all `want-to-sell-post`s are being displayed, and the meta_query is being ignored. What's the error in the way I'm writing this?

Thanks so much!

```
<?php
    $artist_id = get_the_ID();

    $want_to_sell = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'want-to-sell-post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key'     => '_wpcf_belongs_artist_id',
        'value'   => $artist_id,
        'compare' => '=',
    ), 
));  
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-1 justify-content-center">
        <?php if ( $want_to_sell->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( $want_to_sell->have_posts() ) : $want_to_sell->the_post(); ?>
                <?php include get_template_directory() . '/includes/containers/marketplace-sell-artist-page.php'    ;?>
            <?php endwhile;?>
            <?php else: ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I already got it. Was missing an extra array() in the meta_query.

My updated code is this:

I'd like to thank this website. Sometimes just posting the question helps me figure it out. What a cool community. Good luck and happy coding, all.

```
<?php
    $artist_id = get_the_ID();

    $want_to_sell = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'want-to-sell-post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_wpcf_belongs_artist_id',
            'value'   => $artist_id,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ), 
));  
?>
```